# What is the plural form of boxing (as in box/package)?

Tags: nouns, gerunds

What is the plural form of the word "boxing"? In meaning box/package noun. Is "boxings" the correct form in that case? Because I think it's not, it's a gerund and not exception.

Comment: We don't speak of _boxing_ in the sense of packaging; only the combat sport and the British name _Boxing Day_ for Dec. 26th.

Comment: @KateBunting - when I was working in a UK legal office (until recently) we used to pack paper records and files in 'file transfer cases', and send them off to storage after 6 months. The process of transferring accumulated paperwork to the cases was called 'boxing up'. Also, there are lots of 'unboxing' product review videos on YouTube. where a phone. laptop, etc is shown being removed from its packaging and demonstrated. I agree that these terms are rather informal. I suppose you might say 'I'm bored with looking at unboxings on Youtube'.

Comment: I should say 'We don't use it as a noun in the packaging sense'. Anyway, this question has been duplicated, and closed, on ELU.